# Bloomberg data redistribution policy

Tags: bloomberg

I've looked through the Bloomberg website, but haven't found any information about available license plans. I'm curious whether it provides any license that allows you to re-distribute data requested from Bloomberg terminal to third-party customers?

Or maybe you can provide any link to documents which regulate re-distribution of their data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to quantitative finance.

Comment: @Gordon, I haven't fount better place within Stack Network

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hit `<BREP> GO` on your terminal and ask.

Though if you have just the terminal then the answer is most likely no.  They allow you to publish charts but they consider using an excel sheet that was populated with data from a terminal on another machine to be a violation of the terminal agreement.

If you use their [B-PIPE,](http://www.bloomberg.com/enterprise/content-data/market-data/) then the license is  a bit more liberal, data can leave the terminal machine but is still only eligible for use within the firm and you can't store it in a database or other storage mechanism.  Though I think this is probably the most broken rule in finance.  Just slightly above, make sure you have borrow before you issue a short order:)

Market data especially won't be redistrubutable as you have a contract with both Bloomberg and the exchange for market data, and exchanges aren't really known for their "liberal" distribution policies:)

Comment: Agreed, the rules are pretty strict. (I once found out I can't even redistribute my own photo, now that it has been entered into the Bbg system and is part of the BIO command!).